# Apex Toolkit: Is the DocumentService.addEnvelopeDocuments method private?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex

When I try to call this method, which is described as a Global Static method in the Apex Toolkit documentation, I get an Apex error that the method is not visible. Therefore I can't use it and I can't figure out another way to use both a Docusign template and Salesforce Document objects in a single envelope (I've been able to send one or the other but not both).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct Global method for adding documents is dfsle.Envelope.withDocuments()
Example code would look something like this:

```
Id docId = 'SF_DOC_ID'

dfsle.Document doc = new dfsle.Document(null, dfsle.Document.TYPE_DOCUMENT, 1, 'Test Document Name', 'pdf', 1234, null, docId);

// template = template stuff if you're doing that

dfsle.Envelope envelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.getEmptyEnvelope(new dfsle.Entity(oppid))
.withDocuments(new List<dfsle.Document> {doc, template})
.withRecipient(recipient stuff);

//send envelope or update
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue I was having, and the reason I was trying to use addEnvelopesDocuments was that I was putting the document Id as the first parameter of the dfsle.Document constructor instead of the last, which was throwing an error when I tried withDocuments(new List<dfsle.Document> {doc, template}) as you have here.